# Loop through lines in file and fill NSMutable array with NSStrings

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array, lines, that consists of the lines in a text file. I want to choose a particular line based on its first string. So I loop through the file like this:

```
for(NSString *str in lines) 
{

    myMutableArray = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"]];

//Get myMutableArray[0] and check if it's the correct line

// If not, empty the NSMutableArray and start over
}
```

I know that the code line inside the loop will return an NSArray, so this won't work. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Hank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myMutableArray = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"]] mutableCopy];
```

Suits?